# Problems with implementing authentication feature in a tapestry web app using tynamo-security module

Tags: java, hibernate, authentication, tapestry, tynamo

I am completely new to tapestry and the tynamo-security module and need your help.

I want to implement an authentication feature on my web app using tynamo-security and hibernate. I followed the instructions [here](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-security%20guide) but it's are not sufficent for me to make it work.

So far I have implemented a user entity and its dao:

```
package com.example.tynamo.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.apache.tapestry5.beaneditor.NonVisual;
import org.apache.tapestry5.beaneditor.Validate;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NonVisual
    private Long id;

    @Validate("required")
    private String firstName;

    @Validate("required")
    private String lastName;

    @Validate("required")
    private String email;

    @Validate("required")
    private String loginName;

    @Validate("required")
    private String password;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String userName, String password){
        this.loginName = userName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLoginName() {
        return loginName;
    }

    public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
        this.loginName = loginName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return loginName + " : " + firstName + " " + lastName + " - " + email + " : " + password;
    }
}


package com.example.tynamo.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;

import com.example.tynamo.dao.UserDAO;
import com.example.tynamo.entities.User;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    public void insertUser(User user) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            System.out.println(session.save(user));
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    public User loadUserById(int id) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        User u = (User) session.load(User.class, id);
        session.close();
        return u;
    }

    public User loadUserByLoginName(String loginName) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        User u = (User) session.createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("loginName", loginName)).uniqueResult();
        session.close();
        return u;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> loadAllUser() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        List<User> list = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }

}
```

Moreover I wrote added some lines in the AppModule:

in the binder method:

```
binder.bind(UserDAO.class, UserDAOImpl.class);
```

... the method as it is described [here](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-security%20guide)

```
public static void contributeSecurityConfiguration(Configuration<SecurityFilterChain> configuration,
            SecurityFilterChainFactory factory)
```

... and a the addRealms method that adds my own UserRalm to the configs.

```
@Contribute(WebSecurityManager.class)
    public static void addRealms(Configuration<Realm> configuration) {
        UserRealm realm = new UserRealm();
        configuration.add(realm);
    }
```

I took the example class for UserRealm from [here](http://svn.codehaus.org/tynamo/trunk/tynamo-federatedaccounts/tynamo-federatedaccounts-core/src/test/java/org/tynamo/security/federatedaccounts/testapp/services/UserRealm.java) and modified it as follows

```
package com.example.tynamo.security;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.shiro.authc.AccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.ExpiredCredentialsException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.LockedAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.SimpleAuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleAuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha1Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection;
import org.apache.shiro.util.SimpleByteSource;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import com.example.tynamo.dao.UserDAO;
import com.example.tynamo.entities.User;

public class UserRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Inject
    UserDAO userDAO;

    public UserRealm() {
        super(new MemoryConstrainedCacheManager());
        setName("localaccounts");
        setAuthenticationTokenClass(UsernamePasswordToken.class);
        setCredentialsMatcher(new HashedCredentialsMatcher(Sha1Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME));
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        if (principals == null) throw new AuthorizationException("PrincipalCollection was null, which should not happen");

        if (principals.isEmpty()) return null;

        if (principals.fromRealm(getName()).size() <= 0) return null;

        String username = (String) principals.fromRealm(getName()).iterator().next();
        if (username == null) return null;

        User user = findByUsername(username);
        // if (user == null) return null;
        // Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>(user.getRoles().size());
        // for (Role role : user.getRoles())
            // roles.add(role.name());
        //return new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(roles);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;

        String username = upToken.getUsername();

        // Null username is invalid
        if (username == null) { throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm."); }

        User user = findByUsername(username);

        //if (user.isAccountLocked()) { throw new LockedAccountException("Account [" + username + "] is locked."); }
        //if (user.isCredentialsExpired()) {
        //  String msg = "The credentials for account [" + username + "] are expired";
        //  throw new ExpiredCredentialsException(msg);
        //}
        //return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, user.getEncodedPassword(), new SimpleByteSource(user.getPasswordSalt()), getName());
        return null;
    }

    private User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDAO.loadUserByLoginName(username);
    }
}
```

I commented out the parts that don't work yet. The user entity that I implemented myself doesn't have the methods asked here and
I can't find any user interface (just the federated) that helps me with implementing these methods. 
What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me with that?

Does tynamo-security also provide pages (and so on) for signup?

Comment: Read up on the concepts please. Start with the Shiro manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you get this to work ?

One of the things that I noticed is that you have instantiated `UserRealm` by yourself and so `@Inject` won't work in there. You can either allow tapestry to instantiate it by using `configuration.addInstance(UserRealm.class)` or pass a reference to the `UserDAO` using constructor.

As you have not mentioned what kind of error you are facing it is difficult to answer it.

Comment: No, I finally found another solution as it is partly described here: http://tapestryjava.blogspot.de/2009/12/securing-tapestry-pages-with.html

Comment: tapestry-security is a wonderful tapestry wrapper over Apache Shiro. It gives you a lot of power and once configured applying rules is very easy. Do consider it in future.